# How to fix gibberish printed after use strtok

Tags: c, string, strtok

I have uni project, I need to check if the syntax is right. I get pointer to a string, and check if the first token acceptable. In case it's OK, i move forward. But in case it's not OK, i need to print what is wrong.

What i did is to create a buffer since i can't change the original string.
After that i use `strtok` to cut the buffer, and look if the token i got is acceptable.

```
char *str = "sz = 12345";
printf("The check of MACRO: %d\n", isMacro(str));

int isMacro(char *str)
{
    char buf = NULL;
    char *token;
    strcpy(&buf,str);
    token = strtok(&buf," ");
    printf("You here, value token is %s\n",token);
}
```

I expected that `printf` would print the 'sz' but it prints:

```
You here, value str is sz<▒R
```

Comment: `isMacro()` misses to return a value, so the out `printf()` might invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    char buf = NULL;
```

This is a type error. `buf` is a single character, but `NULL` is a pointer value. You can't store a pointer in a `char`.

```
    strcpy(&buf,str);
```

This code has undefined behavior (unless `str` happens to be an empty string). `buf` is not a buffer, it is a single `char`, so it does not have room to store a whole string.

If you want to make a copy of a string, you need to allocate enough memory for all of its characters:

1. You could use `strdup` (which is in POSIX, but not standard C):

   ```
   char *buf = strdup(str);
   if (!buf) {
       ... handle error ...
   }
   ...
   free(buf);
   ```
2. You could replicate `strdup` manually:

   ```
   char *buf = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
   if (!buf) {
       ... handle error ...
   }
   strcpy(buf, str);
   ...
   free(buf);
   ```
3. You could use a variable-length array (but you're limited by the size of your stack and you have no way to check for errors):

   ```
   char buf[strlen(str) + 1];
   strcpy(buf, str);
   ...
   ```

Comment: Why does `char buf = NULL` even compile?

Comment: @Ayxan On some platforms `NULL` is defined as `0`, not `((void *)0)`, so the code effectively becomes `buf = '\0'`. Other compilers treat (some) type errors as optional warnings, not hard errors.

Answer (score 0):

`buf` is a single `char` instead of a `pointer` to a `char`. In fact, if you're planning to do `strcpy` to copy a string to it, you need to allocate memory first using malloc. Instead I'd suggest you to use a function like `strdup` instead of `strcpy` to create a copy of the original string to modify it using strtok. Remember to `free` the `strdup`ed string later.

Something like this.

```
int isMacro(char *str)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    char *token;
    buf = strdup(str);
    token = strtok(buf," ");
    printf("You here, value of token is %s\n",token);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions, but worth noting `strdup` is not part of the c standard library (it's POSIX), so some compilers may not provide it (in which case your `strlen, malloc` and `memcpy` suggestion is fine)

Comment: `isMacro()` misses to return a value.